# put multiple items in dictionary

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary

```
dict.add "orange", array("200","newyork","2023-2-28")

if range("A1")="orange" then
  cells("B1")= dic.item("orange")
```

i want to put multiple items into dictionary using array and extract value into cells, not only array anyother way to put multiple items into dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

try this add method then
Use the .Add method in a loop:

```
              Dim dictnew As New Dictionary
              Dim fruits(3) As String
                   fruits(0) = "apple"
                   fruits(1) = "banana"
                   fruits(2) = "orange"

                       For i = 0 To UBound(fruits)
                          dictnew.Add fruits(i), "Some value"
                       Next i
```

Comment: Please format your answer correctly, see how do I write a good answer [answer].

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with array

```
Sub test1()
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add "orange", Array(200, "newyork", #2/28/2022#)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        If .Range("A1") = "orange" Then
            arr = dict("orange")
            .Range("B1").Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]